# Multiple notifications from one form in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So we have a has_many :through association. A Classroom has_many Students through ClassroomStudents.

Students are added through the classroom_new form, and in a nested form, so creating ClassroomStudents go through the Classroom Controller and not the ClassroomStudent controller.

I am working on creating notifications to notify parents when a student is added to a classroom. But only one notification is created no matter how many students are added and the student id isn't saved. How can I create multiple notifications out of one form?

Classroom Controller Create Method (ClassroomStudenets are created here too)

```
def create
    @classroom = current_user.classrooms.create(classroom_params)
    @classroom_student = ClassroomStudent.new
    @student = @classroom_student.student_id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @classroom.save
        format.html { redirect_to @classroom, notice: "Classroom successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @classroom }
        if @classroom_student.save
          @student = @classroom_student.student_id
          create_notification @classroom, @classroom_student, @student
        end
      else
        format.html { render :new, alert: "Failed to create classroom." }
        format.json { render json: @classroom.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Create Notification method in the Classroom Controller

```
def create_notification(classroom, classroom_student, student)
    Notification.create(user_id: current_user.id,
    #this is temporary, it will soon be the student.parent_id
                        notified_by_id: current_user.id,
                        student_id: classroom_student.student_id,
                        identifier: classroom.id,
                        notice_type: 'add student')

  end
```

Defining Params in the controller

```
def classroom_params
    params.require(:classroom).permit(:name, :image, :description, student_ids: [])
  end

  def classroom_students_params
    params.require(:classroom_student).permit(:student_id, :classroom_id, student_ids: [])
  end
```

Classroom New Form

```
<title>Create a Class - Kidznotes</title>
<div class="authform">
<h2><center>Create a Classroom</center></h2>
<%= simple_form_for @classroom do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.input :image %>
  <h6>This image will be on your classroom banner</h6>
  <br>
  <%= f.label :classroom_students %>
  <br>
    <div class="form-3-col">
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes :student_ids, Student.all, :id, :first_name %>

    </div>
  <br>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>

class Notification
belongs_to :student
belongs_to :notified_by, class_name: 'User'  
end
```

Classes have many notifications and so do Users, but not Classroom Students or Students (students are account types, they are treated as objects created by parents)

Here is what is saved in the database:

```
 #<Notification id: 21, user_id: 3, notified_by_id: 3, post_id: nil, identifier: 76, notice_type: "add student", read: false, created_at: "2017-07-11 13:54:11", updated_at: "2017-07-11 13:54:11", student_id: nil>
```

**I've been stuck on this for longer than I'd like to admit, so thanks ahead of time for any feedback.**

Comment: You probably have a validation error that's causing your calls to `create` to not succeed. Try replacing your calls to `create(...)` with `create!(...)` so that it raises an exception while you're trying to debug and show you where the validation is failing (and records are not being saved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `@classroom_student.student_id` **will always** be `nil` because `@classroom_student` is just *new instance* of `ClassroomStudent` **without** any `params`. <s>AFAIK, when using *many-to-many* relationship, there is no need to save the third model explicitly.</s> You should use `association.create` instead.That said, you don't need `@classroom_student`at all.You should access the `params[:classroom][student_ids]` from the form and pass those to `create_notification` method to create multiple notifications. So your `create` method should like this

```
def create
  @classroom = current_user.classrooms.new(classroom_params)
  @classroom.students.create

  #create notifications for multiple students
  params[:classroom][:student_ids].each do |student|
    create_notification @classroom, student
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    if @classroom.save
      format.html { redirect_to @classroom, notice: "Classroom successfully created." }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @classroom }
    else
      format.html { render :new, alert: "Failed to create classroom." }
      format.json { render json: @classroom.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Finally, tweak your `create_notification` method like below

```
def create_notification(classroom, student)
    Notification.create(user_id: current_user.id,
    #this is temporary, it will soon be the student.parent_id
                        notified_by_id: current_user.id,
                        student_id: student,
                        identifier: classroom.id,
                        notice_type: 'add student')
  end
```

Comment: Do you by any chance know how I'd define students (defining them to get their id for the notification)? I was going to do @classroom_student.find(params[:student_id]) or something with Classroom Students, but that's not defined. If I change student_id: student to student_id: student.id I get undefined method `id' for "1":String error. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @MaxLeoTony Try `ClassroomStudent.find(student)`

Comment: I got this: Couldn't find ClassroomStudent with 'id'=1, the student ID is right, but it's looking for the ClassroomStudent with that id

Comment: Undefined method with @classroom.create_students

Comment: NoMethodError in ClassroomsController#create
undefined method `create_students' for #<Classroom:0x007f4e40f35df0>

Comment: @MaxLeoTony oops it should be `@classroom.students.create`

Comment: I don't want to create new classrooms in the classroom, I just want to identify those added by Classroom Students, that line creates a new student.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148921/discussion-between-pavan-and-maxleotony).